# security flaw - veracode report - crlf injection

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, code-injection

I got the veracode report for my javaEE app. It had a flaw at any logging (using log4j), so I add the `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(log)` to all of them, but veracode keeps reporting them as security flaws.

Is this a right solution?
What else can I do?

This is the report info:
Title:
Improper Output Neutralization for Logs

Description:
A function call could result in a log forging attack. Writing unsanitized user-supplied data into a log file allows an
attacker to forge log entries or inject malicious content into log files. Corrupted log files can be used to cover an
attacker's tracks or as a delivery mechanism for an attack on a log viewing or processing utility. For example, if a web
administrator uses a browser-based utility to review logs, a cross-site scripting attack might be possible.

Recommendations:
Avoid directly embedding user input in log files when possible. Sanitize user-supplied data used to construct log
entries by using a safe logging mechanism such as the OWASP ESAPI Logger, which will automatically remove
unexpected carriage returns and line feeds and can be configured to use HTML entity encoding for non-alphanumeric
data. Only write custom blacklisting code when absolutely necessary. Always validate user-supplied input to ensure
that it conforms to the expected format, using centralized data validation routines when possible.

They recommend to use ESAPI, but it is a very big project so I need the simplest solution, tht's why I tried with String.escape 'StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(log)'

Thx in advanced!

Comment: Can you provide more information from the Veracode report?  Of course strip it of any identifying info

Comment: I would like to know why this very old problem isn't easily handled by a cross-cutting JVM flag or by Spring or SLF4J or something?  Why doesn't Java provide a (safe) logger for every object and call it a day... logging is way more complicated that it should be IMO. (My 2 cents after adding Encode.forJava() to hundreds of lines of code for at least 5 years.)

Answer (score 10):

I head up the Veracode Application Security Consulting group, and can answer your question in detail. The best venue for the conversation is through Support@veracode.com, since the discussion may involve specific details about your findings that we probably want to avoid making public.

The short answer is the StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava() is effective at eliminating typical CRLF risk, but it is not one of the mechanisms our system automatically recognizes as there are situations in which it may be insufficient.

The Veracode system has a mechanism for marking these findings appropriately so they do not cause confusion.

Please contact Veracode Support (support@veracode.com), and we'll be able to talk in detail.

Best regards, 
Jim.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on the approved mechanisms Veracode looks for?

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues conflated in this report.

Firstly, there is log injection - using a newline character to spill over into a separate log line. `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` produces output that has line delimiters and non-ASCII characters escaped, which in principle ensure this problem is fixed. Veracode doesn't know that, though - as an automated scanner it doesn't know enough about what that method is doing to be able to say for sure, so it has to report there might still be a vulnerability there. Naturally Veracode can't know about every escaping function in third-party library code.

Log injection can also happen when you are using your own separators inside a log line, for example `Bad thing happened with parameters {0} and {1}`. In this case if an attacker had the string `" and "` in one of the parameters you wouldn't be able to recreate exactly which data was in which parameter. The answer here is to surround the parameters with delimiters that don't appear in the output of the escaping function - for example put double quotes around each value and use `escapeJava` to escape any double quote character in the value.

The second attack happens outside your application, when some tool is being used to view the logs. If that tool has an injection vulnerability, then metacharacters in the log data can become active. The classic example is viewing logs in a web interface that copies them directly into the page without escaping, resulting in HTML injection and consequently cross-site-scripting in the log viewing application.

If you can be sure that you're only viewing logs in tools that don't suffer from stupid bugs like this, you don't need to worry about it.

Otherwise, try to escape any metacharacters from languages you think might be affected. Typically `<` and `&` for HTML. If you don't want to be HTML-escaping all your non-HTML log data, another way you could do it would be to replace those characters with escaped equivalents like `\u003E` in the output of `escapeJava`.

Again, Veracode won't be able to work out automatically that what you're doing is necessarily safe there so you'll have to mark those reports as ignored/dealt-with once you're happy with it.

Comment: I upvoted this but I want to comment on the "flaw in tool used to view the log file": If the tool has a flaw, the tool should be fixed. There is no good/sensible way to make log data "safe" for broken tools.

Comment: Indeed. However, back in the day, the ‘tool used to view the log file’ might have been IE, in which case you had two problems: firstly HTML tags in a text log causing the file to be sniffed as text/html, and secondly files being viewed off the local machine ending up in the My Computer Zone, which was at that time highly-privileged enough to be able to execute arbitrary code via ActiveX. Luckily both MIME-sniffing and the Zone permissions have been tamed since then so problems with HTML in log files are much rarer.

Comment: Using IE to view log files? That's about as smart as putting a bullet into a gun, look down the barrel and fire it into your eye to **see** whether it works.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into the same issue and I'm generally ignoring this flaw for a simple reason: A logger just gives me a log event. It shouldn't care about **formatting** (exposing sensitive data is another issue).

The solution here is to add proper filtering/post-processing in the **appender** which writes the log event to the log file. At this step, you can remove special characters (`\0`, `\r` - carriage return, `\b` - backspace, `\x1b` - escape and `\x7f` - delete) and replace `\n` with `\n...` to make it impossible to inject fake log lines into the log.

When you do this, you can safely ignore all these flaws.

Also, if a sysadmin uses the wrong tools to look at log files (anything which executes escape sequences, `\r` and backspace), he should be fired.

Answer (score 2):

As I could observe (and understand from messages from Veracode) following should be done:

- new line characters to be removed, so that logs can not be forged (by generating input which can mimic log entries)
- certain characters to be escaped/encoded to mitigate attacts against log viewing tools

This can achieved by using `encodeForHtml()` encoding method from ESAPI library. However the library requires some extra configuration (ESAPI.properties) which is redundant if you just want to escape logged values. To overcome this I extracted (and slightly modified) the escaping code. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HtmlEncoder {

  private static final char REPLACEMENT_CHAR = '\ufffd';
  private static final String REPLACEMENT_HEX = "fffd";
  private static Map<Character,String> characterToEntityMap; // statically initialized
  /**
   * Initialize an array to mark which characters are to be encoded. Store the hex
   * string for that character to save time later. If the character shouldn't be
   * encoded, then store null.
   */
  private static final String[] encodedCharsCache = new String[256];

  public String encodeForHTML(String input) {
    return encode(input);
  }

  // note: bases encodeForHTML() from ESAPI. Unfortunately ESAPI requires configuration in properties which
  // is a pain if you just need to encode
  private String encode(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
      char c = input.charAt(i);
      sb.append(encodeCharacter(c));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private static String toHex(char c) {
    return Integer.toHexString(c);
  }

  private static String getHexForNonAlphanumeric(char c)  {
      // note: we cache only up to 256 characters (ASCII)
    return c < 0xFF ? encodedCharsCache[c] : toHex(c);
  }

  private String encodeCharacter( Character c ) {

    // check for immune characters
    if ( c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '-' || c == '_' || c == ' ') {
      return ""+c;
    }

    // check for alphanumeric characters
    String hex = getHexForNonAlphanumeric(c);
    if ( hex == null ) { // means we should not encode the character
      return ""+c;
    }

    // check for illegal characters
    if ( ( c <= 0x1f && c != '\t' && c != '\n' && c != '\r' ) || ( c >= 0x7f && c <= 0x9f ) )
    {
      hex = REPLACEMENT_HEX; // Let's entity encode this instead of returning it
      c = REPLACEMENT_CHAR;
    }

    // check if there's a defined entity
    String entityName = (String) characterToEntityMap.get(c);
    if (entityName != null) {
      return "&" + entityName + ";";
    }

    // return hex representation of entity
    return "&#x" + hex + ";";
  }

  static {
    for ( char c = 0; c < 0xFF; c++ ) {
      if ( c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39 || c >= 0x41 && c <= 0x5A || c >= 0x61 && c <= 0x7A ) {
        encodedCharsCache[c] = null;
      } else {
        encodedCharsCache[c] = toHex(c).intern();
      }
    }

    Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<Character,String>(252);

    map.put((char)34,  "quot"); /* quotation mark */
    map.put((char)38,  "amp");   /* ampersand */
    map.put((char)60,  "lt");  /* less-than sign */
    map.put((char)62,  "gt");  /* greater-than sign */
    map.put((char)160, "nbsp"); /* no-break space */
    map.put((char)161, "iexcl");  /* inverted exclamation mark */
    map.put((char)162, "cent"); /* cent sign */
    map.put((char)163, "pound");  /* pound sign */
    map.put((char)164, "curren"); /* currency sign */
    map.put((char)165, "yen");   /* yen sign */
    map.put((char)166, "brvbar"); /* broken bar */
    map.put((char)167, "sect"); /* section sign */
    map.put((char)168, "uml");   /* diaeresis */
    map.put((char)169, "copy"); /* copyright sign */
    map.put((char)170, "ordf"); /* feminine ordinal indicator */
    map.put((char)171, "laquo");  /* left-pointing double angle quotation mark */
    map.put((char)172, "not");   /* not sign */
    map.put((char)173, "shy");   /* soft hyphen */
    map.put((char)174, "reg");   /* registered sign */
    map.put((char)175, "macr"); /* macron */
    map.put((char)176, "deg");   /* degree sign */
    map.put((char)177, "plusmn"); /* plus-minus sign */
    map.put((char)178, "sup2"); /* superscript two */
    map.put((char)179, "sup3"); /* superscript three */
    map.put((char)180, "acute");  /* acute accent */
    map.put((char)181, "micro");  /* micro sign */
    map.put((char)182, "para"); /* pilcrow sign */
    map.put((char)183, "middot"); /* middle dot */
    map.put((char)184, "cedil");  /* cedilla */
    map.put((char)185, "sup1"); /* superscript one */
    map.put((char)186, "ordm"); /* masculine ordinal indicator */
    map.put((char)187, "raquo");  /* right-pointing double angle quotation mark */
    map.put((char)188, "frac14"); /* vulgar fraction one quarter */
    map.put((char)189, "frac12"); /* vulgar fraction one half */
    map.put((char)190, "frac34"); /* vulgar fraction three quarters */
    map.put((char)191, "iquest"); /* inverted question mark */
    map.put((char)192, "Agrave"); /* Latin capital letter a with grave */
    map.put((char)193, "Aacute"); /* Latin capital letter a with acute */
    map.put((char)194, "Acirc");  /* Latin capital letter a with circumflex */
    map.put((char)195, "Atilde"); /* Latin capital letter a with tilde */
    map.put((char)196, "Auml"); /* Latin capital letter a with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)197, "Aring");  /* Latin capital letter a with ring above */
    map.put((char)198, "AElig");  /* Latin capital letter ae */
    map.put((char)199, "Ccedil"); /* Latin capital letter c with cedilla */
    map.put((char)200, "Egrave"); /* Latin capital letter e with grave */
    map.put((char)201, "Eacute"); /* Latin capital letter e with acute */
    map.put((char)202, "Ecirc");  /* Latin capital letter e with circumflex */
    map.put((char)203, "Euml"); /* Latin capital letter e with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)204, "Igrave"); /* Latin capital letter i with grave */
    map.put((char)205, "Iacute"); /* Latin capital letter i with acute */
    map.put((char)206, "Icirc");  /* Latin capital letter i with circumflex */
    map.put((char)207, "Iuml"); /* Latin capital letter i with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)208, "ETH");   /* Latin capital letter eth */
    map.put((char)209, "Ntilde"); /* Latin capital letter n with tilde */
    map.put((char)210, "Ograve"); /* Latin capital letter o with grave */
    map.put((char)211, "Oacute"); /* Latin capital letter o with acute */
    map.put((char)212, "Ocirc");  /* Latin capital letter o with circumflex */
    map.put((char)213, "Otilde"); /* Latin capital letter o with tilde */
    map.put((char)214, "Ouml"); /* Latin capital letter o with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)215, "times");  /* multiplication sign */
    map.put((char)216, "Oslash"); /* Latin capital letter o with stroke */
    map.put((char)217, "Ugrave"); /* Latin capital letter u with grave */
    map.put((char)218, "Uacute"); /* Latin capital letter u with acute */
    map.put((char)219, "Ucirc");  /* Latin capital letter u with circumflex */
    map.put((char)220, "Uuml"); /* Latin capital letter u with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)221, "Yacute"); /* Latin capital letter y with acute */
    map.put((char)222, "THORN");  /* Latin capital letter thorn */
    map.put((char)223, "szlig");  /* Latin small letter sharp sXCOMMAX German Eszett */
    map.put((char)224, "agrave"); /* Latin small letter a with grave */
    map.put((char)225, "aacute"); /* Latin small letter a with acute */
    map.put((char)226, "acirc");  /* Latin small letter a with circumflex */
    map.put((char)227, "atilde"); /* Latin small letter a with tilde */
    map.put((char)228, "auml"); /* Latin small letter a with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)229, "aring");  /* Latin small letter a with ring above */
    map.put((char)230, "aelig");  /* Latin lowercase ligature ae */
    map.put((char)231, "ccedil"); /* Latin small letter c with cedilla */
    map.put((char)232, "egrave"); /* Latin small letter e with grave */
    map.put((char)233, "eacute"); /* Latin small letter e with acute */
    map.put((char)234, "ecirc");  /* Latin small letter e with circumflex */
    map.put((char)235, "euml"); /* Latin small letter e with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)236, "igrave"); /* Latin small letter i with grave */
    map.put((char)237, "iacute"); /* Latin small letter i with acute */
    map.put((char)238, "icirc");  /* Latin small letter i with circumflex */
    map.put((char)239, "iuml"); /* Latin small letter i with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)240, "eth");   /* Latin small letter eth */
    map.put((char)241, "ntilde"); /* Latin small letter n with tilde */
    map.put((char)242, "ograve"); /* Latin small letter o with grave */
    map.put((char)243, "oacute"); /* Latin small letter o with acute */
    map.put((char)244, "ocirc");  /* Latin small letter o with circumflex */
    map.put((char)245, "otilde"); /* Latin small letter o with tilde */
    map.put((char)246, "ouml"); /* Latin small letter o with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)247, "divide"); /* division sign */
    map.put((char)248, "oslash"); /* Latin small letter o with stroke */
    map.put((char)249, "ugrave"); /* Latin small letter u with grave */
    map.put((char)250, "uacute"); /* Latin small letter u with acute */
    map.put((char)251, "ucirc");  /* Latin small letter u with circumflex */
    map.put((char)252, "uuml"); /* Latin small letter u with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)253, "yacute"); /* Latin small letter y with acute */
    map.put((char)254, "thorn");  /* Latin small letter thorn */
    map.put((char)255, "yuml"); /* Latin small letter y with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)338, "OElig");  /* Latin capital ligature oe */
    map.put((char)339, "oelig");  /* Latin small ligature oe */
    map.put((char)352, "Scaron"); /* Latin capital letter s with caron */
    map.put((char)353, "scaron"); /* Latin small letter s with caron */
    map.put((char)376, "Yuml"); /* Latin capital letter y with diaeresis */
    map.put((char)402, "fnof"); /* Latin small letter f with hook */
    map.put((char)710, "circ"); /* modifier letter circumflex accent */
    map.put((char)732, "tilde");  /* small tilde */
    map.put((char)913, "Alpha");  /* Greek capital letter alpha */
    map.put((char)914, "Beta"); /* Greek capital letter beta */
    map.put((char)915, "Gamma");  /* Greek capital letter gamma */
    map.put((char)916, "Delta");  /* Greek capital letter delta */
    map.put((char)917, "Epsilon");  /* Greek capital letter epsilon */
    map.put((char)918, "Zeta"); /* Greek capital letter zeta */
    map.put((char)919, "Eta");   /* Greek capital letter eta */
    map.put((char)920, "Theta");  /* Greek capital letter theta */
    map.put((char)921, "Iota"); /* Greek capital letter iota */
    map.put((char)922, "Kappa");  /* Greek capital letter kappa */
    map.put((char)923, "Lambda"); /* Greek capital letter lambda */
    map.put((char)924, "Mu");  /* Greek capital letter mu */
    map.put((char)925, "Nu");  /* Greek capital letter nu */
    map.put((char)926, "Xi");  /* Greek capital letter xi */
    map.put((char)927, "Omicron");  /* Greek capital letter omicron */
    map.put((char)928, "Pi");  /* Greek capital letter pi */
    map.put((char)929, "Rho");   /* Greek capital letter rho */
    map.put((char)931, "Sigma");  /* Greek capital letter sigma */
    map.put((char)932, "Tau");   /* Greek capital letter tau */
    map.put((char)933, "Upsilon");  /* Greek capital letter upsilon */
    map.put((char)934, "Phi");   /* Greek capital letter phi */
    map.put((char)935, "Chi");   /* Greek capital letter chi */
    map.put((char)936, "Psi");   /* Greek capital letter psi */
    map.put((char)937, "Omega");  /* Greek capital letter omega */
    map.put((char)945, "alpha");  /* Greek small letter alpha */
    map.put((char)946, "beta"); /* Greek small letter beta */
    map.put((char)947, "gamma");  /* Greek small letter gamma */
    map.put((char)948, "delta");  /* Greek small letter delta */
    map.put((char)949, "epsilon");  /* Greek small letter epsilon */
    map.put((char)950, "zeta"); /* Greek small letter zeta */
    map.put((char)951, "eta");   /* Greek small letter eta */
    map.put((char)952, "theta");  /* Greek small letter theta */
    map.put((char)953, "iota"); /* Greek small letter iota */
    map.put((char)954, "kappa");  /* Greek small letter kappa */
    map.put((char)955, "lambda"); /* Greek small letter lambda */
    map.put((char)956, "mu");  /* Greek small letter mu */
    map.put((char)957, "nu");  /* Greek small letter nu */
    map.put((char)958, "xi");  /* Greek small letter xi */
    map.put((char)959, "omicron");  /* Greek small letter omicron */
    map.put((char)960, "pi");  /* Greek small letter pi */
    map.put((char)961, "rho");   /* Greek small letter rho */
    map.put((char)962, "sigmaf"); /* Greek small letter final sigma */
    map.put((char)963, "sigma");  /* Greek small letter sigma */
    map.put((char)964, "tau");   /* Greek small letter tau */
    map.put((char)965, "upsilon");  /* Greek small letter upsilon */
    map.put((char)966, "phi");   /* Greek small letter phi */
    map.put((char)967, "chi");   /* Greek small letter chi */
    map.put((char)968, "psi");   /* Greek small letter psi */
    map.put((char)969, "omega");  /* Greek small letter omega */
    map.put((char)977, "thetasym"); /* Greek theta symbol */
    map.put((char)978, "upsih");  /* Greek upsilon with hook symbol */
    map.put((char)982, "piv");   /* Greek pi symbol */
    map.put((char)8194,  "ensp"); /* en space */
    map.put((char)8195,  "emsp"); /* em space */
    map.put((char)8201,  "thinsp"); /* thin space */
    map.put((char)8204,  "zwnj"); /* zero width non-joiner */
    map.put((char)8205,  "zwj");   /* zero width joiner */
    map.put((char)8206,  "lrm");   /* left-to-right mark */
    map.put((char)8207,  "rlm");   /* right-to-left mark */
    map.put((char)8211,  "ndash");  /* en dash */
    map.put((char)8212,  "mdash");  /* em dash */
    map.put((char)8216,  "lsquo");  /* left single quotation mark */
    map.put((char)8217,  "rsquo");  /* right single quotation mark */
    map.put((char)8218,  "sbquo");  /* single low-9 quotation mark */
    map.put((char)8220,  "ldquo");  /* left double quotation mark */
    map.put((char)8221,  "rdquo");  /* right double quotation mark */
    map.put((char)8222,  "bdquo");  /* double low-9 quotation mark */
    map.put((char)8224,  "dagger"); /* dagger */
    map.put((char)8225,  "Dagger"); /* double dagger */
    map.put((char)8226,  "bull"); /* bullet */
    map.put((char)8230,  "hellip"); /* horizontal ellipsis */
    map.put((char)8240,  "permil"); /* per mille sign */
    map.put((char)8242,  "prime");  /* prime */
    map.put((char)8243,  "Prime");  /* double prime */
    map.put((char)8249,  "lsaquo"); /* single left-pointing angle quotation mark */
    map.put((char)8250,  "rsaquo"); /* single right-pointing angle quotation mark */
    map.put((char)8254,  "oline");  /* overline */
    map.put((char)8260,  "frasl");  /* fraction slash */
    map.put((char)8364,  "euro"); /* euro sign */
    map.put((char)8465,  "image");  /* black-letter capital i */
    map.put((char)8472,  "weierp"); /* script capital pXCOMMAX Weierstrass p */
    map.put((char)8476,  "real"); /* black-letter capital r */
    map.put((char)8482,  "trade");  /* trademark sign */
    map.put((char)8501,  "alefsym");  /* alef symbol */
    map.put((char)8592,  "larr"); /* leftwards arrow */
    map.put((char)8593,  "uarr"); /* upwards arrow */
    map.put((char)8594,  "rarr"); /* rightwards arrow */
    map.put((char)8595,  "darr"); /* downwards arrow */
    map.put((char)8596,  "harr"); /* left right arrow */
    map.put((char)8629,  "crarr");  /* downwards arrow with corner leftwards */
    map.put((char)8656,  "lArr"); /* leftwards double arrow */
    map.put((char)8657,  "uArr"); /* upwards double arrow */
    map.put((char)8658,  "rArr"); /* rightwards double arrow */
    map.put((char)8659,  "dArr"); /* downwards double arrow */
    map.put((char)8660,  "hArr"); /* left right double arrow */
    map.put((char)8704,  "forall"); /* for all */
    map.put((char)8706,  "part"); /* partial differential */
    map.put((char)8707,  "exist");  /* there exists */
    map.put((char)8709,  "empty");  /* empty set */
    map.put((char)8711,  "nabla");  /* nabla */
    map.put((char)8712,  "isin"); /* element of */
    map.put((char)8713,  "notin");  /* not an element of */
    map.put((char)8715,  "ni");  /* contains as member */
    map.put((char)8719,  "prod"); /* n-ary product */
    map.put((char)8721,  "sum");   /* n-ary summation */
    map.put((char)8722,  "minus");  /* minus sign */
    map.put((char)8727,  "lowast"); /* asterisk operator */
    map.put((char)8730,  "radic");  /* square root */
    map.put((char)8733,  "prop"); /* proportional to */
    map.put((char)8734,  "infin");  /* infinity */
    map.put((char)8736,  "ang");   /* angle */
    map.put((char)8743,  "and");   /* logical and */
    map.put((char)8744,  "or");  /* logical or */
    map.put((char)8745,  "cap");   /* intersection */
    map.put((char)8746,  "cup");   /* union */
    map.put((char)8747,  "int");   /* integral */
    map.put((char)8756,  "there4"); /* therefore */
    map.put((char)8764,  "sim");   /* tilde operator */
    map.put((char)8773,  "cong"); /* congruent to */
    map.put((char)8776,  "asymp");  /* almost equal to */
    map.put((char)8800,  "ne");  /* not equal to */
    map.put((char)8801,  "equiv");  /* identical toXCOMMAX equivalent to */
    map.put((char)8804,  "le");  /* less-than or equal to */
    map.put((char)8805,  "ge");  /* greater-than or equal to */
    map.put((char)8834,  "sub");   /* subset of */
    map.put((char)8835,  "sup");   /* superset of */
    map.put((char)8836,  "nsub"); /* not a subset of */
    map.put((char)8838,  "sube"); /* subset of or equal to */
    map.put((char)8839,  "supe"); /* superset of or equal to */
    map.put((char)8853,  "oplus");  /* circled plus */
    map.put((char)8855,  "otimes"); /* circled times */
    map.put((char)8869,  "perp"); /* up tack */
    map.put((char)8901,  "sdot"); /* dot operator */
    map.put((char)8968,  "lceil");  /* left ceiling */
    map.put((char)8969,  "rceil");  /* right ceiling */
    map.put((char)8970,  "lfloor"); /* left floor */
    map.put((char)8971,  "rfloor"); /* right floor */
    map.put((char)9001,  "lang"); /* left-pointing angle bracket */
    map.put((char)9002,  "rang"); /* right-pointing angle bracket */
    map.put((char)9674,  "loz");   /* lozenge */
    map.put((char)9824,  "spades"); /* black spade suit */
    map.put((char)9827,  "clubs");  /* black club suit */
    map.put((char)9829,  "hearts"); /* black heart suit */
    map.put((char)9830,  "diams");  /* black diamond suit */

    characterToEntityMap =  Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);

  }
}
```

Now having that function you can log your entries in following way:

```
// below can be static (to be shared), or the method HtmlEncoder#encodeForHtml can be made static for easier usage.. but just to illustrate
private HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder = new HtmlEncoder(); 

logger.info("I wanted to log param: [{}]", htmlEncoder.encodeForHTML(someVariable));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(log) to avoid the HTML injections and might solve your problem.

Comment: I did this and Veracode continued to report an crlf issue. I had to add `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(raw)` in order to convince Veracode.